# 12.10 Desktop install stuck on checksum function

Tags: installation, 12.10

Installing 12.10 Desktop i386 via USB and not winning so far. Following http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest and it gets to step 9 displaying the screen "Learn more about Ubuntu while the system install..." and then it changes to a black screen with a small spinning wheel and the following text on top:

[   7.232452] xor: automatically using best checksumming function:

[   7.272005]    pIII_see : 1856.000 MB-sec

And then it just stays there. Its installing on a brand new 500GB HDD as the only system. I tried Windows XP before but it failed as it seemed like my XP CD was damaged. So I'm trying Ubuntu as advised by many but so far not getting anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
This is my first attempt at Ubuntu or any Linux based OS.

thanks
Neville

Comment: Did you check the iso ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: I downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Do I really need to check Ubuntu's own iso's?

Comment: Yes, to see if the download is corrupt.

Comment: Ok, MD5 checksum verified and correct. However when getting the hash to check for my iso from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes, I noticed there is an iso for AMD... I downloaded ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso as that is the only option ubuntu.com gives? Do I need the AMD iso for my PC as it has an AMD CPU? If so, how do I get that iso?

Comment: Please elaborate on your system specs. Which AMD CPU? How old? A 500GB HDD may indicate that it is a non-PAE-enabled CPU that won't run the generic PAE kernel.

Comment: Its an AMD Athlon XP 3000+, about 7 yours old. Was running fine when HDD failed, only reason I'm rebuilding...then Win XP CD got damaged.

Comment: 7VT600P-RZ(-C) motherboard with VIA KT600 chipset. 1.5GB RAM, and an ATI Radeon graphics card, can't remember exactly which one now...I'd have to go dig out the old boxes.

Comment: Ran the "Try Ubuntu" option first from the USB iso and it runs ok. So then thought I'd try and install it from there i.e. via the "Install Ubuntu" shortcut on the desktop... Run through the same installation wizard as before and got stuck at the same point. Only difference is now instead of stuck on a black screen as stated above, I have the Ubuntu desktop from the "Try out" install with a spinning wheel... sigh!

Comment: Off to bed now as it's 23h40 here and I need to work in the morning. will give this a another try late tomorrow afternoon. Thanks in advance for any further suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so 12.10 is not for older machines. Read other posts where users complained about similar experiences. I even tried installing from CD instead of USB in case my USB was faulty, same results.

I eventually found an old 8.04 build lying around, popped that in and it installed like a dream. It is currently upgrading to 10.something and I'll see how far it goes.

Bottom line, if you're running an older machine with older hardware, perhaps stay clear of 12.10 for now.